# PowerMock and Android TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy When Mocking BluetoothDevice

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, powermock

My issue is that I'm trying to mock BluetoothDevice for some testing, but it's a final class. So, to mock it with PowerMock, I have to use the `@PrepareForTest` annotation. However, when I say `@PrepareForTest({BluetoothDevice.class})`, I get an exception. Here's the first few lines of the error output:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(Unknown Source)
```

And here's the code that I'm using (the tests still need to be filled out, I was just reducing variables):

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ BluetoothDevice.class })
public class BluetoothCommTest {
    @Test
    public void testBluetoothComm() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was going on. I was following the instructions on [this page](https://sites.google.com/site/androiddevtesting/), and the android.jar they provided was out of date, and didn't include the Bluetooth libraries.

To fix this, I used Powermock 1.2.5 and the android.jar that was included with the Android 15 SDK.